# DataStage warning - [IBM (DataDirect OEM)][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation

Tags: sql, sql-server, datastage

This is the full warning I am getting for a DataStage job that is not Failing but just throwing this Warning

Warning message:

JobName..Transformer_2: [IBM (DataDirect OEM)][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation

Any ideas experts ?

Comment: Sounds like data that is being inserted is getting truncated due to it being longer than the target field.

Answer (score 0):

The output size is shorter that the one of the input

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you have a WHERE clause in your (lookup?) stage like this:
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = ORCHESTRATE.COLUMN
and in this case database column COLUMN_NAME is shorter than the column coming on the input like (ORCHESTRATE.COLUMN)